# Prove that: if $a_i$ are postive integers, then $\Sigma \sqrt[n]{a_i}$ is rational iff $\forall _i \sqrt[n]{a_i} \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

If for $1\leq i \leq k$: $a_i$ are postive integers and $k$ is a arbitrary integer , then $\Sigma \sqrt[n]{a_i}$ is rational iff $\forall _i \sqrt[n]{a_i} \in \mathbb{Q}$.

I tried a couple of times, but I still cannot solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the bounds of the sum? In other words, what set does the index $i$ belong to?

Comment: $1\leq i \leq k$ for arbitrary natural k. For $1\leq i \leq k$  $a_i$ are positive natural integers.

Comment: So, add this to your question.